# Is this the correct syntax for inputing a string to an if statement or am i completely off?

Tags: java, oop, for-loop

```
package travelCost;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class travelCost {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Scanner function
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        //define problem variables
        //first
        double distance;
        double mpg;
        double pricePerGallon;
        double milesPerKwh;
        double pricePerKwh;
        double totalCostGas;
        double totalCostElec;
        String type;




//Here i want the user to input a string and then based upon the answer //section into the for loop
        System.out.println("Enter whether the car is 'elec' or 'gas': ");


        type = in.next();
        if (type.equals("elec"))
        {

            System.out.println("Enter the Total Distance in Miles: ");
            distance = in.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter the total Miles per Kwh: ");
            milesPerKwh = in.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter the Total Price per Kwh: ");
            pricePerKwh = in.nextDouble();
            totalCostElec = (distance/milesPerKwh) * pricePerKwh;
            System.out.printf("The trip is going to cost $%5.2f: ", totalCostElec);

        } else if (type.equals("gas: ")
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the Miles per Gallon: ");
            mpg = in.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter the total Price per Gallon of Gasoline: ");
            pricePerGallon = in.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter the total Price per Gallon of Gasoline: ");
            pricePerGallon = in.nextDouble();
            totalCostGas = (distance/mpg) * pricePerGallon;
            System.out.printf("The trip is going to cost $%5.2f", totalCostGas);

        }else
        {
            System.out.println("Please resubmit entry");
        }

        System.out.println();






    }
}
```

Comment: `type.equals("gas: ")` will never be true and should probably use `"gas"` as the string instead - see [Scanner.next](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()) for what it will return.

Comment: realize this now. thanks a ton

Comment: @AdrianStubbs, plz mark the answer or close the question if you solve it successfully. Otherwise, ppl will need to do trouble shooting again :) Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the corrections which mentioned by Paul, here is the complete code:

**travelCost.java**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        double distance;
        double mpg;
        double pricePerGallon;
        double milesPerKwh;
        double pricePerKwh;
        double totalCostGas;
        double totalCostElec;
        String type;

        System.out.println("Enter whether the car is 'elec' or 'gas': ");

        type = in.next();
        if (type.equals("elec")) {
            System.out.println("Enter the Total Distance in Miles: ");
            distance = in.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter the total Miles per Kwh: ");
            milesPerKwh = in.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter the Total Price per Kwh: ");
            pricePerKwh = in.nextDouble();
            totalCostElec = (distance / milesPerKwh) * pricePerKwh;
            System.out.printf("The trip is going to cost $%5.2f: ",
                    totalCostElec);

        } else if (type.equals("gas")) {
            System.out.println("Enter the Total Distance in Miles: ");
            distance = in.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter the Miles per Gallon: ");
            mpg = in.nextDouble();
            System.out
                    .println("Enter the total Price per Gallon of Gasoline: ");
            pricePerGallon = in.nextDouble();
            System.out
                    .println("Enter the total Price per Gallon of Gasoline: ");
            pricePerGallon = in.nextDouble();
            totalCostGas = (distance / mpg) * pricePerGallon;
            System.out.printf("The trip is going to cost $%5.2f", totalCostGas);

        } else {
            System.out.println("Please resubmit entry");
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
```

**Input:**

> elec 100 10 2

**Output:**

> The trip is going to cost $20.00:

Answer (score 0):

make it
`else if (type.equals("gas"))`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @1l13v: Hi, it is the answer to run the program successfully. Because he/she make syntax error i.e. missing `)`. Also redundant `: `. Hence, he/she cannot execute the statements  on the `else if-block`

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 problems with this:

1. The line `} else if (type.equals("gas: ")` needs another `)` at the end.
2. In the `"gas"` case, you are using the variable `distance` but you do not give it a value.
3. While `if (type.equals("elec"))` is the correct syntax (answering your question), it is usually better to write `if ("elec".equals(type))` because this will not throw a `NullPointerException` if `type == null`.
4. It should be `"gas"`, not `"gas: "`.

Answer (score 0):

As Paul mentions, your if statement syntax is correct, but it is good practice to start with the hard coded strings ("elec" and "gas") in order to avoid NullPointerExceptions.  As mentioned in the other answers, the if else should be using "gas" instead of "gas: ".  To help avoid those kinds of errors, you might consider making "elec" and "gas" into static final String constants. If you use constants, you'll know that they are the same throughout your program.  You might also want to call type.toLowerCase() in the event that the user enters the response in uppercase.